# How to create autocomplete field from normal textbox and a list in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, jquery, custom-list, spservices

I [found](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/fields-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-2010-using-jquery-spservi/) a method how to add an autocomplete function to a simple textbox by using the following code:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/JS/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "SupportListName",
            sourceColumn: "SupportColumnName",
            columnName: "TargetColumnName",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
        });
    });</script>
```

What I did:

1. I created 2 list. List "A" have a text column to support the autocomplete function. List "B" have a simple textfield what should be autocomplete when the user start to write.
2. I went to the input display of the "B" target list (New item).
3. I added script editor web part from "Media and content".
4. I copyed the script from the link.
5. Modyfied the names of the lists.

Result: When I save the script editor I can see an error message for a sec: "AsyncDeltaManager.ParseErrorExeption: The messege recived from the server could not be parsed". And nothing happens.
I am new to both Jquery and Sharepoint so it can be even a trivial mistake. Also the guide was for SP 2010 and I am using 2013.

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Comment: Looks like SPServices.SPAutocomplete is not working in SP 2013 I tried most of the popular examples on my side and no worked :(  we need confirmation from @Marc D Anderson

Comment: I have implemented this and it works fine. But it gives the suggestions that **starts with** the input, I want it to show the suggestions that **contains** the text input. For example, If I type 'a', it should show the names that contain 'a' but not the ones that start with 'a'. Please suggest the modification to be done in the above code. Thanks
sandhya v

Comment: The above code is working for me, but it is also accepting new values which are not part of source list. How can we restrict new text which is not available in the source list. i also wanted a link to add new item in the source list (that should be available as 'ADD new item' under description). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have just tried this code in SharePoint 2013 on-premises on a list's NewForm.aspx and it worked. This should work in SharePoint O365 as well. The solution is to use correct jquery and spservices js files.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
            sourceList: "ListA",
            sourceColumn: "Title",
            columnName: "Title",
            ignoreCase: true,
            numChars: 2,
            slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
        });
    });
</script>
```

See output below

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Sounds cool. May I ask you to explain how can I configurate the  jquery and spservices js correctly? I tryed your script, but still not works. Or if it sould works for me too, than it may be my company's SP 2013 installation problem. (For example 2013 workflows not works here too)

Comment: @Nefri, please open the page in Chrome and use Inspect (Right-Click) then go to Network tab and see if there are any js load errors. It appears that jquery or spservices js files are not loading on your page.

Comment: I have 2 warning, but not errors.

1. "window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead"

2. "webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated and will be removed in M57, around March 2017. Please use 'indexedDB' instead"

Both related to AsyncDeltaManager$_navigate and AsyncDeltaManager$_retrieveDelta, but I am not sure what does these mean.

Comment: @Nefri, now you need to go one step back to make sure jquery and spservices work. Add a new web part page and add a content editor web part. Paste this code in the web part. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () { alert(1234);});</script>`. Do same for SPServices. Use the simple method `alert($().SPServices.Version())`. Check for any errors in console and network tabs in Chrome Inspect window

Comment: If I add any of these code I get an error: "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'path.aspx?…ew=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server did not send an 'X-XSS-Protection' header." But if I go to an other list and come back to this one, the error is gone and only that 2 warning is here what I described earlier. Do u have any suggestion what can be the problem? And thank you very much for keep helping me!

Comment: The XSS error usually comes in chrome when we add javascript in cewp. In IE create a site and apply seatle master page. Add the same test javascript in cewp on a page. Now test in chrome and see for any error.

Comment: In the end I foulnd the problem.
1. I had to import the js file's into my page's assets.
2. I used a space in a column's name and looks like I was naive to make is work like this. I changed to the column ID and it works now.
Thanks you very much for all suggestions and help!